# Установка фокуса на EditText. requestFocus не работает

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

В xml у `editText` есть эти 2 атрибута:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Пытался установить фокус с помощью такого кода:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable {
    @Override
    run() {
        try {
            while (v == null) Thread.sleep(15);
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        editText.requestFocus();
        ((InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .toggleSoftInput(SHOW_FORCED, HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
}, 300);
```

Не работает.

Подробнее.
В Navigation Drawer-е нажимаю кнопку, он закрывается, дальше во фрагменте (вкладки) пытаюсь установить фокус.

Никакие задержки не помогли.
`editText.requestFocus()` возвращает `true`.

Добавил к `View`, на который хочу установить фокус, `OnFocusChangeListener`.
Сначала `hasFocus` равен `true`, а потом `false`. По ходу кто-то перехватывает фокус.

Thread Dupm при `hasFocus==false`:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at ru.obrazcenter.Utils$1MyFocusListener.onFocusChange(MyUtils.java:19)
  at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:4836)
  at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7641)
  at android.view.View.clearFocusInternal(View.java:4728)
  at android.view.View.unFocus(View.java:4762)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.unFocus(ViewGroup.java:822)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.unFocus(ViewGroup.java:822)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.unFocus(ViewGroup.java:822)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:624)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:630)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.requestChildFocus(ScrollView.java:1397)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:630)
  at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4610)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.handleFocusGainInternal(ViewGroup.java:604)
  at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:6999)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6978)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2369)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ScrollView.java:1433)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2373)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6945)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1296)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```